# How to disable clientwindow feature in jsf 2.2

Tags: jsf-2.2, java-6

I am running an jsf2.2 application and using Primefaces with JAVA 1.6, i am trying to disable the client window feature which removes the jfwid.Please suggest me how i can handle this issue.

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? Tried the latest? Older Mojarra versions had a bug wherein the flow/window ID is permanently added to navigation outcomes even though the application didn't use it anywhere.

Comment: i am using myfaces-2.2.8, primefaces-5.2, an di also see disableClientWindow set to true for p:button but not for p:commandButton,Please suggest me if i am missing any thing,Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the ClientWindow feature is disabled by default.  The following JavaDoc details the behavior:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/lifecycle/ClientWindow.html#CLIENT_WINDOW_MODE_PARAM_NAME

Also I'm not sure why disableClientWindow would be expected on a p:commandButton(h:commandButton) as that is a POST request whereas the p:button(h:button) would be a GET request.

Looking at the vld docs for the h:commandButton you'll see there is not a disableClientWindow attribute but on the h:button there is.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried disable it to all application on web.xml, but without any success. I tried the follow:

```
<context-param> 
      <param-name>javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindow.CLIENT_WINDOW_MODE_PARAM_NAME</param-name> 
      <param-value>none</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

**The only way that I got it to work was using it on code before a redirect, for example:**

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getClientWindow().disableClientWindowRenderMode(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
return "/home?faces-redirect=true";
```

**Or using it on own button or link:**

```
<a jsf:disableClientWindow="true" target="_blank" jsf:outcome="go_to_anywhere?faces-redirect=true">GoToAnywhere</a>
```